# javascript Instagram login Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error

Tags: javascript, authentication, instagram, instagram-api

I follow the step for [client login on Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/), I configured my app on [instagram client manager](https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/)

My webapp follows this steps:

1. I change url in `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=<MY_CLIEND_ID>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/&response_type=code`
2. I authorize my webapp
3. The url become `http://localhost:8080/?code=<INSTAGRAM_ACCESS_TOKEN>`
4. I call ( Ajax GET request ) `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=<INSTAGRAM_ACCESS_TOKEN>`

**But i get this error:**

```
Failed to load https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=INSTAGRAM_ACCESS_TOKEN : Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the same Ajax using CORSA API, prefix “https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/“ + URL, adding CORSA should bypass CORS easily. :)